# Python: Class Variables copied in all instances hogs memory

Tags: python, oop, class-variables

I have hundreds of generated template Python classes and each class has a lot of meta data about the class like attributes, etc. in a single variable named "meta". The meta might be close to 40k and whenever I create an instance of the class, I am assuming Python is reserving memory for the instance of "class Variables". In the below case, I am using a class variable but even then the memory balloons to a huge amount. Is there a way to not allocate memory for the class variables when the instances are created?

Please correct me if the assumption that Python allocates memory is incorrect.

I am using Python2.7 and hence range expands to a list.

For e.g. on Mac. (On CentOS, remove the second 1024)

```
import resource

class Blah:
    x = range(1,10000)

ll = [Blah() for i in xrange(1,100000)]

print(str(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss / 1024 / 1024) + 'MB')
```

Comment: It should *not* make a copy of that range, since it is a "singleton" class attribute, not an instance attribute. What numbers are you seeing? Is it perhaps just the overhead of the instance itself?

Comment: Python allocates memory for the `__dict__` associated with each object instance, and this allocation can be substantial. It is not allocating memory for "copies" of that `x` class attribute. By the way you should use the new-style classes and inherit your class from `object` (i.e., `class Blah(object):...`).